# Excel range based on cell

Tags: excel, range, cell

I want to change my formula to be more based on cells.
In this formula I have

```
$E$2:$E$471
$D$2:$D$471
$E$2:$E$471
$D$2:$D$471
$C$2:$C$471
```

Instead of `471` I want to get this number from cell `$G$24`.
I tried to use INDIRECT CONCATENATE but this formula is getting too complicated for me. Could you please change my current formula?

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($E$2:$E$471;$H2;$D$2:$D$471;"<>"&$G$3)>0;TEXTJOIN(" &" & CHAR(10);TRUE;IF(($E$2:$E$471=$H2)*($D$2:$D$471<>$G$3);$C$2:$C$471;"")); "")
```

I tried to use INDIRECT CONCATENATE but this formula is getting too complicated for me.

Comment: Make sure there is no data after row 471 then just address the columns ie C:C etc